# In Ruby on Rails, is there a clean way to get the URL but just the front part? (only up to the domain name)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails (version 3), `request.url` can show

```
http://www.foo.com/products/123
```

but what about just to get

```
http://www.foo.com
```

or

```
http://www.foo.com/
```

?  There are 2 apparent ways, one is using regular expression, which is not very clean, and the other is

```
"#{request.scheme}://#{request.host}"
```

and it is kind of ugly either.  Is there a cleaner to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you what `request.url` gets you, but without the path:

```
request.protocol + request.host_with_port
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with request.domain.

Comment: `request.domain` is `foo.com` and it is a String object.

Answer (score 0):

Should be stored in the request object. request.domain should get the info you need but use this command to retrieve all the information from the object and have a look at what is stored there

```
raise request.inspect
```

more info can be found at

http://rails.nuvvo.com/lesson/6377-action-controller-the-request-and-response-objects